# How to setup passkey authentication in Linux?

Tags: debian, pam, lmde, fido-u2f

I have [setup](https://gist.github.com/pavinjosdev/0d7ade586e4b4a33d03a19c7684e78ce) the PAM module `pam_u2f.so` for FIDO2 as the primary authentication method on my LMDE 5 (based on Debian 11) machine.

Is there a way to integrate passkey support with this PAM module or with another?

Specifically I'm looking for the ability to use Google [passkeys](https://passkeys.dev/device-support/) in addition to my hardware security key (Yubikey).

There are several advantages to using a passkey from Google/Apple with the potential privacy downside:

1. The credentials are tied to the Google account and synced across all Google devices, so any device can be used as an authenticator
2. Not tied to a physical object that can be lost/stolen
3. Main point for lazy me: no need to remove a lost/stolen/damaged key from every website and device it's configured on

Chrome browser on Linux sends a push notification via Bluetooth to a nearby Android smartphone for FIDO2/WebAuthn registration/authentication. Can the `pam_u2f.so` module (or some other) be configured to send out a similar request and receive its response instead of looking for a locally connected USB security key?

Comment: Interesting question - I have just started considering moving to passkeys and found that you can self-host a server solution to avoid the (potential) privacy issues you describe: https://github.com/teamhanko/hanko . Following this question! (and will report back should I find anything useful)

Comment: I reckon it couldn't hurt to just ask the friendly people over at linux-pam: https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/issues/616

Comment: And looks like sssd/IPA are working on (at least partially) implementing passkey support - there already is a pam_sss module, so maybe this is currently the most advanced way forward: https://testdays.fedoraproject.org/events/168

Comment: I know this is not exactly the question, but it is realted. I created an [issue](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/30402) for SystemD to somehow expose the systemd-credentials as a service to store these passkey secrets in a TPM. In this way you could use your own device with a TPM chip to authenticate. Right now BTW the Bitwarden browser extensions do [support this](https://bitwarden.com/passwordless-passkeys/), both storing and signing into, making it a very well rounded credential storage solution.